# recursion error when trying to update record in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use signals to update a record, and am getting a "recursion error".

What I am trying to achieve: When a new customUser is saved into database, I want to see if the user inputted a serial number into deviceSerial Field. If there is a serial number, I want to set "isDevice" to True, as it defaults to false. 
The problem seems to occur when I use .save(). I'm assuming I need to use some type of update command instead?

**Error message:**

```
Exception Type: RecursionError
Exception Value: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Exception Location:  
C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\copyreg.py in __newobj__, line 88
Python Executable:   
C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
```

**My models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from defaults.models import DefaultDMLSProcessParams
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/media/photos')

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    customerTag = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default = False,)
    isDevice = models.BooleanField(default = False,) 
    notifications = models.BooleanField(default = True,)
    deviceSerial= models.CharField(max_length=50,) 
    equipmentName= models.CharField(max_length=50,default=(str(equipment)+str(id)),)
    equipmentDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    image = models.ImageField(storage=fs, blank = True)



def create_machine(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    hasSerial = len(instance.deviceSerial) 
    if hasSerial >1:
        newRecordID = instance.id #grab id of record that was just saved
        newRecord = CustomUser.objects.get(id=newRecordID) #get object
        newRecord.isDevice = True #set to True
        newRecord.save(update_fields=['isDevice']) #save it
    else:
        #future code
        pass
post_save.connect(create_machine, sender = CustomUser)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use the `update()` method of the model manager:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(isDevice=True)
```

But instead of multiple database hits you can use the `pre_save` signal.  In this case you can set `isDevice` attribute before saving the instance:

```
def set_is_device(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    hasSerial = len(instance.deviceSerial) 
    if hasSerial > 1:
        instance.isDevice = True
pre_save.connect(set_is_device, sender=CustomUser)
```

Comment: Thanks! Much less code with your version as well. Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are calling the `.save()` method in `post_save` signal on the same model object. That means that you are creating the endless loop, as the `post_save` will trigger after every `.save()` call. The solution would be to use `pre_save` signal and modify `isDevice` value before the `.save()` call. Basic example:

```
def create_machine(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    if instance.deviceSerial:
        instance.isDevice = True #set to True
    else:
        #future code
        pass
pre_save.connect(create_machine, sender = CustomUser)
```